# Image Segmentation Tensorflow tutorials

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation, autoencoder, unet-neural-network

In this [tf tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/segmentation), the U-net model has been divided into 2 parts, first contraction where they have used Mobilenet and it is not trainable. In second part, I'm not able to understand what all layers are being trained. As far as I could see, only the last layer conv2dTranspose seems trainable. Am I right?

And if I am how could only one layer is able to do such a complex task as segmentation?

Tutorial link: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/segmentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for the `Image Segmentation Model`, from the [Tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/segmentation) is shown below:

```
def unet_model(output_channels):
  inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[128, 128, 3])
  x = inputs

  # Downsampling through the model
  skips = down_stack(x)
  x = skips[-1]
  skips = reversed(skips[:-1])

  # Upsampling and establishing the skip connections
  for up, skip in zip(up_stack, skips):
    x = up(x)
    concat = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()
    x = concat([x, skip])

  # This is the last layer of the model
  last = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(
      output_channels, 3, strides=2,
      padding='same')  #64x64 -> 128x128

  x = last(x)

  return tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)
```

First part of the Model is `Downsampling` uses not the entire `Mobilenet Architecture` but only the `Layers`,

```
'block_1_expand_relu',   # 64x64
'block_3_expand_relu',   # 32x32
'block_6_expand_relu',   # 16x16
'block_13_expand_relu',  # 8x8
'block_16_project'
```

of the Pre-Trained Model, `Mobilenet`, which are `non-trainable`.

Second part of the Model (which is of your interest), before the layer, `Conv2DTranspose` is `Upsampling` part, which is present in the `list`,

```
up_stack = [
    pix2pix.upsample(512, 3),  # 4x4 -> 8x8
    pix2pix.upsample(256, 3),  # 8x8 -> 16x16
    pix2pix.upsample(128, 3),  # 16x16 -> 32x32
    pix2pix.upsample(64, 3),   # 32x32 -> 64x64
]
```

It means that it is accessing a Function named `upsample` from the Module, `pix2pix`. The code for the Module, `pix2pix` is present in this [`Github Link`](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/tensorflow_examples/models/pix2pix/pix2pix.py).

Code for the function, `upsample` is shown below:

```
def upsample(filters, size, norm_type='batchnorm', apply_dropout=False):
  """Upsamples an input.
  Conv2DTranspose => Batchnorm => Dropout => Relu
  Args:
    filters: number of filters
    size: filter size
    norm_type: Normalization type; either 'batchnorm' or 'instancenorm'.
    apply_dropout: If True, adds the dropout layer
  Returns:
    Upsample Sequential Model
  """

  initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer(0., 0.02)

  result = tf.keras.Sequential()
  result.add(
      tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters, size, strides=2,
                                      padding='same',
                                      kernel_initializer=initializer,
                                      use_bias=False))

  if norm_type.lower() == 'batchnorm':
    result.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
  elif norm_type.lower() == 'instancenorm':
    result.add(InstanceNormalization())

  if apply_dropout:
    result.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))

  result.add(tf.keras.layers.ReLU())

  return result
```

This means that the second part of the `Model` comprises of the `Upsampling Layers`, whose functionality is defined above, with the Number of `Filters` being `512, 256, 128 and 64`.